# TeamCity Schedule Trigger run on last Monday of each month

Tags: teamcity

In TeamCity, how do I schedule my trigger to run every last Monday every month?
I've tried:

```
Seconds: 0
Minutes: 0
Hours: *
Day of month: L
Month: *
Day of week: 2
Year: *
```

But I get an error message saying:

```
Support for specifying both a day-of-week AND a day-of-month parameter is not implemented.
```

Is there a way for me to achieve what I'm trying to achieve at all? Or is there a workaround I can use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this that explained this to me: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html
TeamCity's documentation link is broken atm of writing this.